# when i add multipart.NewWriter(body_buf), the program will not stop

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "bytes"
)

var channel chan string = make(chan string)

func recognize(file_path string) {
    body_buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    fmt.Println(body_buf)

    send_writer := multipart.NewWriter(body_buf)
    fmt.Println(send_writer)
}

func loop() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        channel <- "dd"
    }
}


func main() {
    go loop()
    for v :=  range channel {
        fmt.Println(len(channel), v)
    }
}
```

the program will not stop,  even i don't call the `recognize` function, i don't know why, how to explain that

when i remove the

`send_writer := multipart.NewWriter(body_buf)`

the program will stop and get fatal error: deadlock

what make it difference, who can tell me

Answer (score 0):

The program will not stop as you never close the channel and thus the range loop over it will not terminate. Close the channel in `loop` like

```
func loop() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        channel <- "dd"
    }
    close(channel)
}
```

and it should stop.

Comment: yes, it will stop. i'm just wondering it will be throw a fatal error `deadlock` when the range loop over,  but when i add `send_writer := multipart.NewWriter(body_buf)`, the error is gone

Comment: The `send_writer := multipart.NewWriter(body_buf)` shouldn't play any part in how the program works with given code. If it does then your actual code is different than the one you posted here.

Comment: that is actual code, i did not call the function, but it does affect the program, my go version is 1.10.2